# Create a table with Variable Columns in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a list with each object structure as follows

```
{
  "regionName": "(R1)",
  "physicalRules": [
    {
      "region": "(R1)",
      "Group": "Strip_10",
      "ClassGroup": "DKC",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "N1",
          "value": "200"
        },
        {
          "name": "N2",
          "value": "14"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a table structure as follows

```
-----------------------------------------------------
(R1)      (R2)          (R3)
N1  N2    N3  N4  N5    N6
200 14    5   10  15    500
```

Where each of R1, R2 & R3 data is in form of objects which has structure defined as above. Only R1 is showed to avoid duplication as R2 & R3 have similar structure. This actually means the number of columns of the table is defined by the number of objects in the list. I am not sure on how to create columns dynamically in an OpenXML table. All examples I see are adding fixed number of columns to the OpenXML table.. Should I create a separate table for each of the objects and join them vertically by columns? I am not sure how to do this either.

```
private void AddTable(Body body, MyVM data)
{

    Table tbl = new();

    // Set the style and width for the table.
    TableProperties tableProp = new();
    TableStyle tableStyle = new() { Val = "TableGrid" };

    // Make the table width 100% of the page width.
    TableWidth tableWidth = new() { Width = "5000", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

    // Apply
    tableProp.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);
    tbl.AppendChild(tableProp);

    // Add 3 columns to the table.
    TableGrid tg = new(new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn());
    tbl.AppendChild(tg);

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        TableRow tr1 = new();
        TableCell tc1 = new(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(item.FirstName))));
        TableCell tc2 = new(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(item.LastName))));
        TableCell tc3 = new(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text($"{item.Age}"))));
        tr1.Append(tc1, tc2, tc3);

        tbl.AppendChild(tr1);
    }
    body.AppendChild(tbl);
}
```

Comment: Is this a table in a Word document, or a sheet in an Excel workbook?  Also what is your starting point-- do you have an existing document part that you want to add this data to, or are you starting from a blank slate?  Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: this is a word document. we have an existing doc that we r copying and adding data we get from backend to this copy. Hence populating some info in tabular form . I currently have the basic Add table code with fixed columns as below. But I need to add columns to be variable based on the data in the list as I showed in my original post and couldn't find any help doc that does that.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.  Could you also post the class definition of `MyVM`?

Comment: As Per the code MyVM =List<Person> with First Name, Last Name & Age. As you can see in the code...
The code actually try to add as many rows as list of Person Objects in the list..But later I realized we need dynamic columns and not rows... thats where I am right now to figure it out.

Comment: The example table you want to build doesn't seem to correspond with the example JSON you gave at the start of the question.  Where in the JSON would (R2), (R3), N3, N4, N5, and N6 appear?  Also, how does that relate to person First Name, Last Name and Age?

Comment: Person is just an example that I took while playing with openXML tables ..PS. I never worked with OpenXML before so still learning..  R2, R3 also have similar structures as I have shown for R1 in the example. Just didn't want to repeat the same structure... Edited the question to include this detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample JSON, I'm assuming your model classes will look like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public List<PhysicalRule> PhysicalRules { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalRule
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string ClassGroup { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can generate your table with the following method:

```
private static void AddTable(Body body, List<Item> data)
{
    Table tbl = new();

    // Set the style and width for the table.
    TableProperties tableProp = new();
    TableStyle tableStyle = new() { Val = "TableGrid" };

    // Make the table width 100% of the page width.
    TableWidth tableWidth = new() { Width = "5000", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

    tableProp.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);

    TableGrid tableGrid = new();  // we will fill this as we go

    // We will create three rows simultaneously, with a variable number of columns in them
    TableRow regionsRow = new();
    TableRow propertyNamesRow = new();
    TableRow propertyValuesRow = new();

    tbl.Append(tableProp, tableGrid, regionsRow, propertyNamesRow, propertyValuesRow);

    int colsAdded = 0;
    foreach (var rule in data.SelectMany(i => i.PhysicalRules))
    {
        var count = rule.Properties.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            TableCell regionCell = new();
            // If there's more than one property in the rule,
            // make the region cell span across those columns
            if (count > 1)
            {
                TableCellProperties cellProperties = new();
                cellProperties.Append(new GridSpan { Val = count });
                regionCell.Append(cellProperties);
            }
            regionCell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(rule.Region))));
            regionsRow.Append(regionCell);

            // Create one column for each property and add
            // the name and value to the the respective rows
            foreach (var prop in rule.Properties)
            {
                tableGrid.Append(new GridColumn());
                colsAdded++;

                TableCell nameCell = new();
                nameCell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(prop.Name))));
                propertyNamesRow.Append(nameCell);

                TableCell valueCell = new();
                valueCell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(prop.Value))));
                propertyValuesRow.Append(valueCell);
            }
        }
    }

    // Don't add the table unless there's something in it
    if (colsAdded > 0) body.AppendChild(tbl);
}
```

Here is the program I used to test the above.  I started with a blank document, which was saved to "Blank.docx".  The program copies this file to a different name and then modifies it using OpenXml.  I believe that is the same process you said you were using.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = "Output.docx";
        File.Copy("Blank.docx", filename, true);

        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
        {
            var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            var items = GetItems();

            AddTable(body, items);

            doc.Save();
            doc.Close();
        }
    }

    private static List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
                RegionName = "(R1)",
                PhysicalRules = new List<PhysicalRule>
                {
                    new PhysicalRule
                    {
                        Region = "(R1)",
                        Group = "Strip_10",
                        ClassGroup = "DKC",
                        Properties = new List<Property>
                        {
                            new Property { Name = "N1", Value = "200" },
                            new Property { Name = "N2", Value = "14" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Item
            {
                RegionName = "(R2)",
                PhysicalRules = new List<PhysicalRule>
                {
                    new PhysicalRule
                    {
                        Region = "(R2)",
                        Group = "Strip_10",
                        ClassGroup = "DKC",
                        Properties = new List<Property>
                        {
                            new Property { Name = "N3", Value = "5" },
                            new Property { Name = "N4", Value = "10" },
                            new Property { Name = "N5", Value = "15" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Item
            {
                RegionName = "(R3)",
                PhysicalRules = new List<PhysicalRule>
                {
                    new PhysicalRule
                    {
                        Region = "(R3)",
                        Group = "Strip_10",
                        ClassGroup = "DKC",
                        Properties = new List<Property>
                        {
                            new Property { Name = "N6", Value = "500" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return items;
    }

    private static void AddTable(Body body, List<Item> data)
    {
        // code as shown earlier in my answer
    }
}
```

Here is the output I got:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Brian Sure..let me try and will come back to you....

Comment: I tried this code but couldn't open the generated word document as MS word says..error while opening similar to this
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-resolve-the-problem-word-experienced-an-error-trying-to-open-the-file-when-opening-a-word-2007-2010-file-easy-fix-article-0903bb9b-d8e4-aabd-0364-f832d26ecff7
None of the fixes suggested worked.

Comment: Hmm, it worked fine for me.  I did get the error you mentioned when there was no data to add to the table.  So I added a check for that case.  But other than that, it worked as expected.  I've updated my answer to show the program I used to test it.  Try that out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah..it worked fine for me after some tweaks....I am playing with it to get the formatting I need...For some reason my table seems to be messed up....I will try few other things and will update....This is helpful....thanks Brian

Comment: No problem; I am glad you got it working.

Comment: If there are more rows for each region? how would we achieve that?? like for eg: we need to add 30, 40 for N1, N2 respectively in R1 in another row similarly few other values for respective properties in R2, R3 and so on....

Comment: How do you tell whether something belongs in a new row as opposed to more columns?  You might be better off asking a new question so you can explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish.  You can add a link back to this question to help provide context if you need to.